# ListView databinding to list of string arrays

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, data-binding

I saw many examples online, about how to realize databinding to an object's attribute. Most people did it by adding the attribute `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}"` to a `GridViewColumn`.

What I want to do is slightly different: I have a `List<string[]>` and I want to add multiple columns dynamically to my `GridView` (which is inside a `ListView` btw.) while the program runs. Every new column should have the content of the specific list element. In fact that means that the first column should list the first string array of the `List`, the second column the second index, etc.

Anyone who knows how to realize that?

Best regards!

Comment: It just does not work that way.  You can bind to a collection of rows but you cannot bind to a collection of columns.  There is nothing in that syntax to know every string[] would even have the same count.  In code behind you can manually create the columns one at a time and bind to string[x].

Comment: Okay, thanks for the response! How can I bind to string[x] and not to an attribute of an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build it up in code behind and just bind to the [x]
Here  DocFields is just a public collection

```
gvBinding = new Binding();
gvBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;                               
gvBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("DocFields[" + FieldIndex.ToString() + "].DispValueShort");
```